# Splitting where lines cross each other using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line

I have 2 lines and I want to make a split where it is crossing each other/intersection point in Qgis 2.16

I have a good picture to see what I really want to do.[image]

Comment: Do you have a preference for what GIS software you want to do this in?

Comment: Have you tried a GIS with topology e.g. GRASS? v.clean command can do it, use tool=break,rmdangle and set a reasonable threshold.

Comment: I use Qgis 2.18

Zoltán esetleg tudnánk beszélni valahol magyarul?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using QGIS 2.18 you can use two tools

**1) v.clean**

**2) Split Line with line in QGIS Toolbox**

Using these two tool you can split the lines where they intersect. You can also run these tool on selected records only as well.